# PHP PDO update error: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I'm having trouble updating an existing database record.  I keep getting `PDOException:  SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.

My assumption is that this means that the number of placeholders (eg `:variable`) in the sql string, does not match the number/name of bound elements.  However, I can't see where my problem is:

```
// arrays for text and numeric form data
$numfield_names = array( "activeTime", "totalTime", "servings" );
$textfield_names = array( "activeTimeDesc", "totalTimeDesc", "yield" );

// get record id
$rid = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'rid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// get text & num fields
$textFields = array();
$numFields = array();
foreach( $textfield_names as $n ){
  $textFields[$n] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $n, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); }
foreach( $numfield_names as $n ){
  $numFields[$n] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $n, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }

try{
  include "dbConnect.php";

  // update recipe data
  $recipeSet = array();
  $recipeData = array('id'=>$rid);
  $recipeFields = array_merge($numFields, $textFields);
  $recipeFields['id'] = $rid;
  foreach( $numFields as $field => $val ){
    $recipeSet[] = "`$field`=:$field";
    $recipeData[$field] = $val;
  }
  foreach( $textFields as $field => $val ){
    $recipeSet[] = "`$field`=':$field'";
    $recipeData[$field] = $val;
  }

  print_r( $numFields );
  print_r( $textFields );

  $recipeSetStr = trim( implode(',', $recipeSet) , ',');
  $sql = "UPDATE `recipes` SET " . $recipeSetStr . " WHERE `id`=:id";

  print_r( $sql );

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":activeTime", $recipeData['activeTime']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":totalTime", $recipeData['totalTime']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":servings", $recipeData['servings']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":activeTimeDesc", $recipeData['activeTimeDesc']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":totalTimeDesc", $recipeData['totalTimeDesc']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":yield", $recipeData['yield']);
  $stmt->bindValue( ":id", $recipeData['id']);
  $stmt->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // return error - I'm only hitting this...
  echo $e->xdebug_message;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Array ( 
[activeTime] => 10 
[totalTime] => 10 
[servings] => 32 
) 

Array ( 
[activeTimeDesc] => 10 minutes 
[totalTimeDesc] => 10 minutes (plus 1 day to make yogurt cheese) 
[yield] => 2 cups 
) 

UPDATE `recipes` SET `activeTime`=:activeTime,`totalTime`=:totalTime,`servings`=:servings,`activeTimeDesc`=':activeTimeDesc',`totalTimeDesc`=':totalTimeDesc',`yield`=':yield' WHERE `id`=:id

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /sites/kaleUI/setRecipe.php on line 77 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0008695680{main}( )../setRecipe.php:0 20.0267722104execute ( )../setRecipe.php:77
```

When I substitute the sql placeholders with the cooresponding data I have no trouble running the update in mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using quotes around the parameter placeholders, which is not right. All placeholders should not be quoted, regardless of type. PDO is only seeing 4 of your 7 placeholders because it doesn't recognise the those in quotes and thus gives the mismatch error. Change this line:

```
$recipeSet[] = "`$field`=':$field'";
```

So it becomes:

```
$recipeSet[] = "`$field`= :$field";
```